# How to Keep Sound Turned Off

Tags: ios, audio

I have a two buttons. One that shows when the sound is playing and one when the sound isn't playing. However, when I switch it off and switch view controllers. And i come back to the main menu view controller the sound is back on. I want to keep the sound on or off based on the user setting.

```
     (IBAction)pauseSound
{
    BOOL shouldPlaySound = YES;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:shouldPlaySound forKey:@"shouldPlaySound"];
    if (![sound isPlaying]) {
        [sound play];
        [soundButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SoundOn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else {
        [sound pause];
        [soundButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SoundOff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Please post some code. My guess is that you either start the music `viewDidAppear` or your view unloads when you "switch" view controllers, so `viewDidLoad` is called again, and the music starts playing there.

Comment: I edited my post and I do call it in the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is saving wether or not to play the Sound in the `NSUserDefaults`, so the setting is remembered by your app. Set it i.e. via

```
BOOL shouldMuteSound = ...//set it corresponding to your button presses/visibility
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:shouldMuteSound forKey:@"shouldMuteSound"];
//call this to immediatly update the userDefaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And load it via

```
BOOL shouldMuteSound = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"shouldMuteSound"];
```

I didn't get it at first that the buttons are inside the same viewController that plays the sound. That code should help you:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    BOOL shouldMuteSound = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"shouldMuteSound"];
    if(!shouldMuteSound){
        [self playSound];
    }else{
        [self stopSound];
    }
} 

- (void)playSound{
     if(!sound){
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Main Menu" ofType:@"mp3"];
        sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
        sound.numberOfLoops = -1;
     }
    if (![sound isPlaying]){
        [sound play];
    }
    [soundButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SoundOn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)stopSound{
    [sound pause];
    [soundButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SoundOff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (IBAction)soundButtonTapped{
   BOOL shouldMuteSound = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"shouldMuteSound"];
   shouldMuteSound = !shouldMuteSound;
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:shouldMuteSound forKey:@"shouldMuteSound"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
   if(shouldMuteSound){
      [self stopSound];
   }else{
      [self playSound];
   }
}
```

Comment: I have never used USERDefaults before so I am a little confused. I have been trying to declare it in the App Delegate But I am getting error messages.

Comment: I want the sound to start running as soon as the app loads. However, Whenever I moved the code to viewDidAppear, it stopped working.

Comment: I see - that's a valid point :) so if the key doesn't exist, the userDefaults will return NO. To get things working, you can either provide a initial value at the begin of appDelegates `applicationDidFinishLaunching` via the first codesnippet or see my edited answer that just flipped the meaning of the boolvalue, so NO means play.

Comment: It works now. Although there's one small problem. Whenever i go back to the view, the picture changes so that it shows that the sound is on. And also, whenever you have the sound on and go back home it starts a new sound.

Comment: Cool. The image is easy to fix: just add an else in viewDidAppear and call stopSound there. I don't understand the second issue: what does 'go back home' mean? And do you mean the sound is restarted or that there are two sounds playing simultaneously?

Comment: I fixed the button image. I mean that whenever i go to a new view controller with the sound on and come back to the main menu a new sound starts.

Comment: Try to add the if (![sound isPlaying]) in playsound see the edited answer.

Comment: It still didnt work. So i just put a viewDidDisappear and canceled the song after the view left.

Comment: Correct, I had to guess if the Problem was restarting or doubled sounds - seems I picked the wrong one. You should have a closer look on how your ViewControllers are presented/dismissed/retained since it sounds like the dismissed one stays in memory and another is created. Going on like this your app will crash due to memory problems.